# Resource key could not be resolved during design time in windows universal apps

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Even though I have declared the resource dictionary in App.xaml, I don't get the Key resolved in my xaml pages during design time. It works fine during runtime. Also my BasePage is not resolved.

[image] 
[image]

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, its my official app, so I cant share the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the XAML designer just get lost. 
If everything is working at runtime, it means that your code is correct. You can try to rebuild you solution to let VS regenerate everything and allow the XAML designer to work again. Sometimes, closing the designer tab and reopening it after a rebuild can help....

Comment: Actually I get these error daily in my App. Also I tried all wat u said earlier itself. Is there any other way to add basepage?

Comment: Did you declare a parameter less constructor for your base page ? The designer is not working properly if a control (page, usercontrol...) is not having a parameter less constructor.

Comment: Yes, my BasePage has parameter less constructor.